# Series convergence test of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1)}{n10^(n-1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given the following series I have to test the convergence. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1)}{n10^(n-1)}$. Then applying d'Alembert method I get: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1{(n+1)10^((n+1)-1)}\frac n10^(n-1){1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n10^(n-1){(n+1)10^((n+1)-1)}=1/10$ which means R=10 so $x\in(-10;10)$. So next I investigate the two cases:
1st when x=10 I substitute it back and get: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{10^n}{n10^(n-1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{10}{n} = 10\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$
2nd when x=-10: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{((-1)^n)10^n}{n10^(n-1)}=10\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$
The question is by what criteria and how do I know which of the two cases the series converges or diverges.

Comment: If I can make a guess while the thing is being edited into shape, $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, say by the Integral Test or Cauchy Condensation or estimates, and $\sum_1^\infty (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}$ converges by the Alternating Series Test aka Leibniz Test.

Comment: But it may be, since I cannot find an $x$ except in the solution, you are only asking about the convergence of $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n10^n}$, and the Ratio Test says it does.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you intend to determine convergence of the series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n10^{n-1}}$$

One way to solve this is to note that $\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n10^{n-1}} < \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ for large enough $N$.  Thus, this series converges by comparison.

You seem to be confusing "finding radius of convergence" (which you do for power series) and "determining convergence" (which you can do for just regular series).  This problem does not require d'Alembert's test (also called the Ratio test).